# Proxy status instead of file when Uploading files

Tags: reactjs, antd

Uploading files using antd Dragger component, everything works fine but when I upload the files, I get Proxy status in response instead of file? What does proxy here represent?

[image]

I am using this example https://ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-drag. Why am I not getting file in response directly?

Comment: That is only relevant to their website. If you open the examples in codesandbox etc they work normally with files.

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue, did you find a solution for this ? In my caseI get two feedbacks, first it's the proxy then I receive the correct File information

Answer (score 0):

Based on [#29614](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/commit/3c7030acb9c341472d23ef2aabd631eb80d859dd)

> Upload should always return new file proxy.

If you need to object install for example antd@4.9.1. Then it returns object to you.